# Why a " sentence" without predicate can stand alone?

Tags: sentence-construction

In the sentence below:

> Five days ago the Evertons left San Francisco in order to extend the family's Mexican history and patch the present onto the past. To find out if there was still copper underground and how much of the rest of it was true, the width of the sky, the depth of the stars, the air like new wine. **To weave chance and hope into a fabric that would clothe them as long as they lived.**

For the sentence in bold, I do not comprehend why it can stand alone ending with a period even if there is no predicate but a infinitive plus a restrictive relative clause. And also the meaning of this "sentence" just elude me completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be a technically correct sentence, it should be punctuated like this:

> Five days ago the Evertons left San Francisco in order to extend the family's Mexican history and patch the present onto the past; to find out if there was still copper underground and how much of the rest of it was true, the width of the sky, the depth of the stars, the air like new wine; (and) to weave chance and hope into a fabric that would clothe them as long as they lived.

Each "to" clause is building off of "in order to." For lists you usually use commas, but if the items in your list are long and contain commas themselves, then use semicolons to divide your list.

The usage of periods and the lack of "and" on the last sentence are to make it seem more dramatic, I suppose, but I don't think I like it.

Comment: I'm not sure the second "to" clause even makes sense. The whole passage should be rewritten if it was up to me.

Comment: I think it's an excellent piece of prose, even though it's obviously a totally unsuitable text for people actually *learning* English. OP missed out a rather charming clause after *the air like new wine* - [***the harsh noons and long, slow dusks.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stars%2C+the+air+like+new+wine%22) Apparently it's from Harriet Doerr's 1978 Booker Prize–winning novel, *Stones for Ibarra*, which imho was a well-deserved win.

Comment: I guess I need the context around this sentence to figure it out. But how is "the air like new wine" supposed to be understood? It doesn't parse as "To find out if the air like new wine,"

Comment: @HiddenBabel 2 I guess "the air like new wine" is following " To find out how much of the rest of it was true," along with  "the width of the sky, the depth of the stars, " acting as an appositive detailing "the rest, " though I would say, based on the grammar I've learned, "the air like new wine" should also phrase in " ...of ...." structure so as to paralell with the other two.

Comment: You can't really "parse" the "syntax" of the cited text, especially of elements like *...the width... the depth... the air...* It's on a par with poetry, "stream of consciousness" prose, etc., which is why it's not a very suitable text for anyone wishing to *learn* English.

Comment: ...the implication is the Evertons have been *told* various things about Mexico (it has easily accessible copper, wide sky, deep stars, air like wine,...). Or at the very least, *that's what they **want** to believe* about their destination.